# How to check if subset Array contains one of the superset arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, subset

I want to create a function that checks if my subset contains one of my supersets in Javascript. It should either return true or false.

There are 7 fixed supersets, each superset is an array of fixed 3 integers, see below:

```
var supersets = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[1, 4, 7],
[2, 5, 8],
[3, 6, 9],
[1, 5, 9],
[3, 5, 7]];
```

The subset is an array as well, but has a random length and are in a random order. For example:

```
var subset1 = [2, 4, 8, 1, 3];
```

or

```
var subset2 = [3, 7, 5];
```

For both these subsets the function should return true
(subset1 contains 1, 2 and 3)(subset2 contains 3, 5 and 7)

But this should return false, because it does not contain any of the supersets:

```
var subset3 = [2, 1, 7, 6]
```

The function should be something like:

```
if (subset contains of of the 7 supersets) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

For the people that would like to know the project i use the code for, it's a Dutch version of the Tic Tac Too game.

```js
var whosTurnElement = document.getElementById("whosTurnElement"),
  errorOutputElement = document.getElementById("errorOutput"),
  fieldOneElement = document.getElementById("fieldOne"),
  fieldTwoElement = document.getElementById("fieldTwo"),
  fieldTreeElement = document.getElementById("fieldTree"),
  fieldFourElement = document.getElementById("fieldFour"),
  fieldFiveElement = document.getElementById("fieldFive"),
  fieldSixElement = document.getElementById("fieldSix"),
  fieldSevenElement = document.getElementById("fieldSeven"),
  fieldEightElement = document.getElementById("fieldEight"),
  fieldNineElement = document.getElementById("fieldNine");

// Switch die aan de hand van een getal het juste element terug geeft
function getCorrespondingElement(field) {
  console.log(playerTurn + "Start switch" + field);
  switch (field) {
    case 1:
      console.log("returing element");
      return document.getElementById("fieldOne");
    case 2:
      return document.getElementById("fieldTwo");
    case 3:
      return document.getElementById("fieldTree");
    case 4:
      return document.getElementById("fieldFour");
    case 5:
      return document.getElementById("fieldFive");
    case 6:
      return document.getElementById("fieldSix");
    case 7:
      return document.getElementById("fieldSeven");
    case 8:
      return document.getElementById("fieldEight");
    case 9:
      return document.getElementById("fieldNine");
  }
};

// Array met winnende compinaties, elke combinatie is opgeslagen als een Array in een Array
var winningMoves = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [3, 6, 9],
  [1, 5, 9],
  [3, 5, 7]
];

// object met de ingevulde vakken
var moves = {

  // Array met player 1 zijn ingevulde vakken
  player1: [],

  // Array met player 2 zijn ingevulde vakken
  player2: []
};

// Check of de moves Array vande spleer overeen komt met een van de de Winning Array
function winCheck(player) {

  // Zet de playerMoves variable naar de huidige player, en sorteert de vakjes
  var playerMoves;
  if (player == "player1") {
    playerMoves = moves.player1.sort();

  } else if (player == "player2") {
    playerMoves = moves.player2.sort();
  }

  // Loopt door de plaermoves heel en kijkt of een een winnende combinatie in zit
  for (var i = 0, l = winningMoves.length; i < l; i++) {
    var found = winningMoves[i].every(function(el) {
      return playerMoves.indexOf(el) > -1;
    });
    if (found) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

// Functie die kijkt of het vakje al is ingevult, het vakje wordt megegeven als parameter
function fieldCheckedCheck(field) {
  var isChecked = false;

  // Loopt door mijn moves Array
  for (var i = 0; i < moves.player1.length; i++) {
    if (moves.player1[i] == field) {
      ischecked = true;
    }
  };

  // Loopt door de computers moves Array
  for (var i = 0; i < moves.player2.length; i++) {
    if (moves.player2[i] == field) {
      ischecked = true;
    }
  };
  return isChecked;
};

// Functie die het ingevulde vakje toevoegd aan het Object met in gevulde vakken. Deze functie krijgt 2 parameters mee, 'player' de huidige speler en 'field' om welk vakje het gaat.
function setMove(player, field) {
  console.log("setMove");
  if (player == "player1") {

    // Kijkt of het vakje al is ingevult
    if (fieldCheckedCheck(field) == true) {

      // Geeft een error weer als het al is ingevult
      errorOutputElement.innerHTML = "Dat vakje is al ingevult";
      return false;

    } else if (fieldCheckedCheck(field) == false) {

      // Voegt het vakje toe aan mijn Array
      moves.player1.push(field);
      console.log(field);

      // Vult het vakje in met een X
      getCorrespondingElement(field).innerHTML = "&times;";
      return true;
    }
  } else if (player == "player2") {

    // Kijkt of het vakje al is ingevult
    if (fieldCheckedCheck(field) == true) {

      // Geeft een error weer als het al is ingevult
      errorOutputElement.innerHTML = "Dat vakje is al ingevult";
      return false;

    } else if (fieldCheckedCheck(field) == false) {

      // Voegt het vakje toe aan mijn Array
      moves.player2.push(field);

      console.log(field);
      // Vult het vakje in met een X
      getCorrespondingElement(field).innerHTML = "&#3664;";

      return true;
    }
  }
};

// Zet de eerste beurt voor Player1
var playerTurn = "player1";

function player1Click(field) {
  if (setMove("player1", field) == true) {
    if (winCheck("player1") == true) {
      window.location.assign = "./player1wins.html";
    } else {
      playerTurn = "player2";
    }
  }
};

function player2Click(field) {
  if (setMove("player2", field) == true) {
    if (winCheck("player2") == true) {
      window.location.assign = "./player2wins.html";
    } else {
      playerTurn = "player1";
    }
  }
};

// Speler 1 aan de beurt is
while (playerTurn == "player1") {
  whosTurnElement.innerHTML = "speler 1";

  fieldOneElement.onclick = player1Click(1);
  fieldTwoElement.onclick = player1Click(2);
  fieldTreeElement.onclick = player1Click(3);
  fieldFourElement.onclick = player1Click(4);
  fieldFiveElement.onclick = player1Click(5);
  fieldSixElement.onclick = player1Click(6);
  fieldSevenElement.onclick = player1Click(7);
  fieldEightElement.onclick = player1Click(8);
  fieldNineElement.onclick = player1Click(9);
}

// Speler 2 aan de beurt is
while (playerTurn == "player2") {
  whosTurnElement.innerHTML = "speler 2";

  fieldOneElement.onclick = player2Click(1);
  fieldTwoElement.onclick = player2Click(2);
  fieldTreeElement.onclick = player2Click(3);
  fieldFourElement.onclick = player2Click(4);
  fieldFiveElement.onclick = player2Click(5);
  fieldSixElement.onclick = player2Click(6);
  fieldSevenElement.onclick = player2Click(7);
  fieldEightElement.onclick = player2Click(8);
  fieldNineElement.onclick = player2Click(9);
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
 body {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f3f4;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
h2 strong {
  color: #83a7d9;
}
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 5vw;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10vh;
  color: #83a7d9;
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10vh;
  bottom: 5vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 85vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section.card {
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  padding: 5vh 5vw;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
}
table td {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #83a7d9;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Boter Kaas en Eiren</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="card">
      <h2>Het is <strong id="whosTurnElement">..</strong> zijn beurt.</h2>
      <p id="errorOutput"></p>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td id="fieldOne"></td>
          <td id="fieldTwo"></td>
          <td id="fieldTree"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="fieldFour"></td>
          <td id="fieldFive"></td>
          <td id="fieldSix"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="fieldSeven"></td>
          <td id="fieldEight"></td>
          <td id="fieldNine"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is, perhaps, a homework question?

Comment: Show us the code have you come up with so far to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Zino. The point of the site is to help you with _specific_ problems with _your_ code. Please try and solve this yourself first.

Comment: "Subset containing superset" is confusing. I would swap the "superset" and "subset" names.

Comment: @christopher It's not a homework question, it's part of a game i'm building Tic-tac-too to be exact.

Comment: @Andy This is just a small part of the code i got stuck at, It's the part of the tic-tac-too game that calculates if a player is winning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More old-school version:

```
function find(superset, subset) {
  for (var i = 0, l = superset.length; i < l; i++) {
    var elementExists = function (el) { return subset.indexOf(el) > -1; }
    if (superset[i].every(elementExists)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

find(superset, subset);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gj3p3rap/2/)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with sets and array methods:

```
var subset = new Set([2, 4, 8, 1, 3]);
supersets.some(arr => arr.every(item => subset.has(item))); // true
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ES2016 arrow functions, so I'am going to stick with the old-school version. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Another step-by-step solution.

```js
function check(a) {
    return supersets.some(function (b) {
        return b.every(function (c) {
            return a.some(function (d) {
                return c === d;
            });
        });
    });
}

var supersets = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]];
document.write(check([2, 4, 8, 1, 3]) + '<br>');
document.write(check([3, 7, 5]) + '<br>');
document.write(check([1, 2, 8]) + '<br>');
```